# Facebook $_GET or $_REQUEST data?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible or not within a facebook tab on a page.

My page url looks like this:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/appname/342342342?v=app_1234234

I simply want to pass it another param like this:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/appname/342342342?v=app_1234234&donated=1

I can do in within the app, but it doesnt work on tab - any ideas?

Tried these two:

```
<?php echo $_GET["donated"]; ?>

<?php echo $_REQUEST["donated"]; ?>
```

Comment: note: those links arent supposed to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wes, I am not sure this is possible at this time.

I am also seeking a solution to this problem. It looks like iFrames in the Tabs will be available soon, and hopefully this change will allow access to the parent URL, similar to iFrame canvas applications.

I have asked a similar question here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/434

Let me know if you come across any solutions!